# Bootstrap Typehead ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out what is wrong in the below code. it's not showing me the dropdown if I type any alphabet. I would be really thankful if someone can throw some light on this.

```
         $('#clientname').typeahead({
         source: function (query, process) {
           $.ajax({
           url: 'data.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data: 'clientname=' + query,
          success: function(data) {     
            console.log(data);
            process(data);

          }
         });
       }
      });
```

Data.php

```
  $clientname=$_POST["clientname"];
   $res=$db->result("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_name LIKE  '%".$clientname."%'");

if($res)
{
foreach($res as $data){
    $return =  json_encode ($data);
}}
$json = json_encode($return);
```

Comment: what does process() function does?

Comment: echo your query to check if its working on your database

Comment: whn im echo. its working properly.. i think the problem the error in AJax post

Comment: Try this code to your inside ajax success function `var resultList = data.map(function (item) {
    var aItem = { id: item.Id, name: item.name };
    return JSON.stringify(aItem);
});
return process(resultList);`

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you double-encoding the array?

Should be:

```
$return = array();
if($res) {
  foreach($res as $data){
    $return[] =  $data;
  }
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Also, beware of your passing the $_POST parameter directly in the query.

Comment: im geting the value in data.php.. but its not return to ajax call